# How to make decorator that shows a message before running a function and hide afterwards in PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyside2

I tried a simple logic to achieve this:

```py
import sys as _sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets as _QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtCore as _QtCore


class CustomDialog(_QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | _QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        layout = _QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = _QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)


def show_message_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        dialog = CustomDialog()
        dialog.label.setText("Executing function...")
        dialog.show()
        _QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()

        result = func(*args, **kwargs)

        dialog.label.setText("Function completed.")
        _QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        dialog.hide()

        return result

    return wrapper


@show_message_decorator
def test_function():
    for i in range(500000):
        print(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = _QtWidgets.QApplication(_sys.argv)
    test_function()
    _sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is not working out though as I am getting the dialog but it is transparent and does not show the message:

[image: A small rectangular transparent overlay]

I am assuming that this is because my main thread is being blocked but I am not sure whether that really is the case and how I can implement threading in my decorator if I really need to go that route.

Comment: You're right about the fact that the function is blocking the main thread. Unfortunately, you cannot do any of that with an arbitrary function, because it gives no control over its execution: in normal situations, all this is achieved by an external thread that periodically releases control to the main one (either on its own, caused by I/O, or programmatically by explicitly yielding like with using `sleep()`). If your function is completely CPU bound, moving it to a thread will probably change nothing. There may be some possibility using async, but unfortunately I've no experience with it.

Comment: After rethinking about it, no, I doubt that async would help you, unless you specifically write the function considering that, or, as said above, it's not completely CPU bound, thus allowing the GIL to temporarily release control from the task (or the thread). If the function *is* CPU bound, and you have no control over its execution (by internally adding "breakpoints" that allow task/thread switching), then it won't change anything, no matter if you use threading or async. For those situations, the only acceptable possibility is to use multiprocessing, which obviously complicates things.

Comment: @musicamante I am a little confused over what you mean by "CPU Bound"? Do you mean to say that my function when running could take control over the CPU thread and not allow other things to run? 

I had mixed results when I was trying to test my code on the functions where I wanna use it, the pop-up would show up just fine. If I switch to using time.sleep() or the print example, my thread gets blocked. Is this related to what you are talking about?

Comment: One thing to note is that I am not handling the event loop as well as the Qt application inside my current decorator. My current use case already has an application as well as event loop running and I am only handling the show() and hide() bits.

I had not included that in my answer because my use case will expand to cover the application and event loop as well in the future. Could that also be changing something?

Answer (score 1):

Okay after testing my previous code the musicamante is right the thread was actually destroyed my bad for not testing it.. I've now run and tested and it should work like this.I did it by creating a worker class to run a function in separated thread as you can see in the example here.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys

class CustomDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def set_message(self, message):
        self.label.setText(message)

# Worker class to run a function in a separate thread
class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.Signal()
    
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def run(self):
        # Execute the provided function with its arguments and keyword arguments
        self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        # Emit a signal to indicate that the work is finished
        self.finished.emit()

def show_message_before_and_after(initial_message, final_message):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # Create or get the application instance
            app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() or QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

            dialog = CustomDialog()
            dialog.set_message(initial_message)
            dialog.show()

            # Create a worker object to run the provided function
            worker = Worker(func, *args, **kwargs)
            thread = QtCore.QThread()

            # Move the worker to the separate thread
            worker.moveToThread(thread)
            
            # Connect signals to manage thread and dialog
            worker.finished.connect(thread.quit)
            worker.finished.connect(dialog.hide)
            worker.finished.connect(worker.deleteLater)
            thread.finished.connect(thread.deleteLater)

            # Start the thread when the worker starts
            thread.started.connect(worker.run)

            thread.finished.connect(lambda: dialog.set_message(final_message))
            thread.finished.connect(dialog.show)
            thread.finished.connect(app.quit)

            # Start the thread and run the application event loop
            thread.start()
            app.exec_()

        return wrapper

    return decorator

@show_message_before_and_after("Executing", "Function executed!")
def test_function():
    for i in range(500):
        print(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_function()
```

Comment: This will probably not work (it didn't in my tests, and it seems strange that it did with you), because no persistent reference for QThread instance `thread` is created, so it will be destroyed while the actual thread is still running. Sorry for asking, but did you actually test it with the given example (possibly, trying to increase the for loop, or adding a sleep)?

Comment: Well I didn't run the code nor did I tested it, I was making assumption based of what I know.If it doesn't work maybe it gets garbage collected before the thread was finished executing, sorry if I was not helpful. Maybe the solution is to store the thread in the instance, and then use workers.

Comment: Sorry, to bother you, but your update is still problematic: it will only work properly if the app event loop is actually started within the wrapper, but an application already exists (a possibility you implied by using `instance()`) and its event loop is already running, then you're back to square one, because `app.exec()` will be ignored (with the console warning "The event loop is already running") and then it will immediately return, destroying the `thread`. A possibility would be to use `QDialog.exec()`, but without ever allowing it to close, as it will make `exec()` return while the »

Comment: » underlying thread is still "closing", but with the garbage collection of `thread` being abrupt. Besides, there's little point in hiding the dialog and showing it again; if you do it in order to recenter it, then it's the wrong way to do it, since it doesn't consider a possibly *shorter* message; instead, `set_message()` should eventually check if the dialog is already visible, then get the current geometry, call `adjustSize()`, center the new `rect()` on the old geometry center, and finally call `setGeometry()`. Still, all this won't resolve the GIL problem if the function is CPU bound.

Comment: Hmm, okay thanks for pointing that out. If the function is CPU bounded then using multiprocessing is the solution or even using the interpreter that doesnt have GIL like Jython or ironpython which are not the best solutions if you need certain features. Ill try to find a better solution using the information given. I am not a native speaker of english so I maybe didn't understand the task at hand, and I am new to writing on stackoverflow. One thing to add maybe to use the concurrent.features, @Parikshit can you explain what tasks are you executing and if they are cpu bound or not?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use async (unless you can guarantee it really works with Qt5 and PySide2. In my case, I have no idea, so I went a little too far to be able to use something similar). In Qt5, we have the QEventLoop class, which can be used to call a blocking function (QEventLoop.exec_), forcing python to wait at a specific line of code, without freezing the whole application.

By using Qt5 QThreads, QObjects and Signals, we can create something very close to a coroutine (a function that can be paused/resumed some time later). This can be very useful to run code without blocking the GIL, as we can combine it with the python's builtin subprocess module, allowing us to easily use multiprocessing in our code.

This is how the example below works when the `Start Task` button is clicked:

1. The QThread is already executing, running its internal QEventLoop;
2. The Worker.run method is scheduled to be executed on the other thread at some time later;
3. A QDialog is shown, telling to the user that the task has started running;
4. A QEventLoop blocks the main thread until the task is done;
5. Worker.run method processes data, periodically emitting the Worker.readline signal, which updates the QDialog label text; It allows the user to see that the application is not frozen/stuck. Its just processing data in the background;
6. When the worker is done, it emits its Worker.done signal, telling that Worker.run is about to go out of scope;
7. As we connected Window.workDone before QEventLoop.quit, Worker.done sends data to Window.workDone first, and then it tells the QEventLoop to stop running;
8. QThread finishes executing Worker.run, and starts processing its internal QEventLoop again;
9. In the main thread, QDialog is hidden;
10. Window.taskStart returns Window._data.

---

Here's the code for the main script:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QLabel, QPushButton
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, QThread, QEventLoop, Signal
import subprocess

TASK_BLOCKS_GIL = False

class Worker(QObject):
    readline = Signal(str)
    done = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        s = ''
        if (TASK_BLOCKS_GIL):
            # Note: shell=True is not safe (shell injection).
            proc = subprocess.Popen('python.exe task.py', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, encoding='utf-8')
            while (True):
                data = proc.stdout.readline()
                if (not data):
                    break
                else:
                    lines = data.split('\n')
                    if (lines[-1] == ''):
                        lines.pop()
                    for ln in lines:
                        s += (ln + '\n')
                        self.readline.emit(ln)
        else:
            for i in range(5):
                ln = 'Processing' + ('.' * i) + '\n'
                s += ln
                self.readline.emit(ln)
                self.thread().sleep(1.0)
            ln = 'Done\n'
            s += ln
            self.readline.emit(ln)

        # When the task is done, emit the signal back
        # It will unlock the eloop and hide the dialog afterwards
        self.done.emit(s)

class Window(QWidget):
    scheduler = Signal() # Alternative to QMetaObject.invokeMethod
    workerDone = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton('Start Task')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.taskStart)

        self.thread = QThread()
        self.thread.start()

        self.dialog = QDialog()
        self.dialog.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.dialog.label = QLabel()
        self.dialog.layout().addWidget(self.dialog.label)

        self._data = None

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        self.thread.quit()
        self.thread.wait()
        e.accept()

    def taskStart(self):
        eloop = QEventLoop()
        equit = lambda *a: eloop.quit()
        
        worker = Worker()
        worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

        # 1. According to our logic:
        # workerDone will receive the worker data before the#
        # event loop quits.
        worker.done.connect(self.workerDone)
        worker.done.connect(equit)
        worker.readline.connect(self.dialog.label.setText)

        self.dialog.show()
        self.dialog.setWindowTitle('Task.py is executing...')

        # 2. Use the scheduler signal to start the worker on the
        # other thread (that must be already running).
        self.scheduler.connect(worker.run)
        self.scheduler.emit()
        self.scheduler.disconnect(worker.run)

        # 3. We can ensure (according to 1.) that self._data will 
        # contain the emited data right before the event loop is 
        # stopped.
        print('WAITING TO COMPLETE TASK... (TASK_BLOCKS_GIL=%s)' % ('Yes' if (TASK_BLOCKS_GIL) else 'No'))
        eloop.exec_()

        worker.done.disconnect(self.workerDone)
        worker.done.disconnect(equit)
        worker.readline.disconnect(self.dialog.label.setText)

        self.dialog.hide()

        print('RECEIVED DATA: ', self._data)
        return self._data

    def workerDone(self, data):
        self._data = data

###
app = QApplication()
win = Window()
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

---

And here's the code for the task.py file (you can copy n paste this file on the same directory as the script above. Setting the global variable `TASK_BLOCKS_GIL` to True will force to execute code from task.py instead).

```
import time

for i in range(5):
    print('Processing' + ('.' * i), flush=True)
    time.sleep(1.0)

print('Done', flush=True)
```

---

Note: This script does not check if you click the Start Task button 2x before the first task had finished its job. It might trigger some unexpected behaviour (In this case, each task will run right after the other has finished, until all tasks finish executing). Disabling the button until the task is done is the easiest way to solve this problem.